# Data are not fully come

Tags: php, web

When sending the data from "admin" (admin.php) page to update data page (update.php) data are not fully reach the page and when you run a query (on update.php) page does not issue error and executes the query, the page just refreshes.

```
'<a href = update.php?id='.$line['id'].'&name='.$line['name'].'&weight='.$line['weight'].'&ingredients='.$line['ingredients'].'&time='.$line['time'].'&price='.$line['price'].'&kid='.$line['kid'].'>Update </a>'
```

So data is sent.

```
$name = trim( $_GET['name'] );
echo '<p><input type="text" value="'.$name.'" name="name"></p>';
```

Data is received

Comment: `data are not fully reach the page`... show more code. How you sent data.. how you get that data..

Comment: Change the `$line['id']` to `$line["id"]` do this for all the variables

Comment: Which bits of data do you receive and which bits do you not receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the querystring you are creating probably has at least one space in it, you must wrap the `href="stuff......"` in quotes.

So try changing your HTML to this:

```
echo '<a href="update.php?id='.$line['id'].'&name='.$line['name'].'&weight='.$line['weight'].'&ingredients='.$line['ingredients'].'&time='.$line['time'].'&price='.$line['price'].'&kid='.$line['kid'].'">Update </a>';
```